# Склонение составного топонима Могилёв-Подольский

Tags: склонение, топонимика

Как склонять [город] Могилёв-Подольский?

Answer (score 1):

Вот что говорит по этому вопросу [Грамота.ру](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/letters/73-rubric-90):

> Если сложносоставной топоним представляет собой русское или давно
>   освоенное название, в косвенных падежных формах его первая часть
>   должна склоняться: из Камня-Каширского, в Переславле-Залесском, в
>   Могилеве-Подольском, в Ростове-на-Дону.

Answer (score 1):

Название, употребленное с родовыми наименованиями *город, село, деревня, хутор,* *река* и др., выступающее в функции приложения, согласуется с определяемым словом, то есть склоняется, если топоним русского, славянского происхождения или представляет собой давно заимствованное и освоенное наименование:

в Петропавловске-Камчатском, в Переяславле-Залесском, во Владимире-Волынском, из Ильиной-Поляны, ***в Могилёве-Подольском***;
в городе Комсомольске-на-Амуре, в селе Никольском-Архангельском, ***из города Могилёва-Подольского.***

Есть особенности.
В некоторых сложных географических названиях первая часть остается без изменений:
в Каменец-Подольске, в Гусь-Хрустальном.
Все топонимы, у которых первая часть названия имеет морфологическую примету среднего рода, охвачены тенденцией к неизменяемости:
из Ликино-Дулева, в Соболево-на-Камчатке, из Лосино-Островской.

[**Склонение частей сложносоставных географических названий**](http://gramma.ru/SPR/?id=3.4)